# How to smooth html webcam video? (very jerky compared to native mobile camera)

Tags: html, css, video

Hi I have a video html element that displays as the viewport to html mobile webcam:

```
<video class="camvideo" height="937" width="1249" autoplay="" muted="" playsinline=""></video>
```

It works well to display like a native mobile camera, however, when you move your mobile phone around, the content became very jerky and not smooth. How to I smooth the video output?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't 'smooth' a video with either HTML or CSS; the video output is the video output.

Comment: @ObsidianAge if not html or css, what else do you recommend that I look into?

Comment: You could try to lower the quality of the video stream by using [MediaStreamTrack.applyConstraints](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/applyConstraints) and a lower quality MediaStreamConstraints ( play with height width and frameRate) but normally the UA should do it itself if all are defaults and it has some difficulties in processing the input stream. Can you reproduce on different browers? Can you also show your initial constraints please? I personnaly can't reproduce on my old Galaxy S6: https://jsfiddle.net/4omc3n0y/embedded/result